# Take an image and set is as the background in android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, background

I was wondering if it were possible to take an image using the camera and then use that image in the background of my application.  I am able to take and preview the image in my app, but don't know how to pass that data to the class that would set it as a background image.  Is there a dynamic way to get this photo and set it as the background in my app?

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Comment: Thanks, But how do i then set that image as the background within my app, not just preview the image taken?

Comment: You need to start a new Camera Intent after that you need to get image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To start the camera intent:**

```
... 
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
...
```

Where PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE is just a integer constant unique within activity to be used as request codes while starting intent for results.

**To Receive photo in the onActivityResult, and update background of the view**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            if (photo != null) {
                // mView should refer to view whose reference is obtained in onCreate() using findViewById(), and whose background you want to update
                mView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code does not use full size photo. For that, you will have to ask Photo intent to save it to a file, and read the file.  Details are present [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)