# How do I take a picture and then set activity background to that picture?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to take a picture with the camera Intent and then immediately set the activity background to that image.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void TakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = SavePicture();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return;
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_layout);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            rl.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Just looking at my code, it doesn't look correct. Too much conversions from classes.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The last 4 lines of your code should be in the `onActivityResult` method.  But what exactly is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: The code just doesn't do anything. It returns no errors and the app runs without crashing though.

Comment: So the camera doesn't even launch?  If the camera doesn't even launch then `photoFile` is probably always null, you haven't shown us the `SavePicture` code.

Answer (score 0):

Check similar [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531515/take-an-image-and-set-is-as-the-background-in-android) solution on that issue.
I think you are looking for a complete solution on this issue. If so, this article would be good one for you:

- [Camera Photo Capture And Show Captured Photo On Activity](http://androidexample.com/Camera_Photo_Capture_And_Show_Captured_Photo_On_Activity_/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=77&aaid=101)